# i cant add change background color on scroll in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to change background color of my navbar on scroll but it keeps giving me this error:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined'
so what is the problem or how can i apply that ?
this is my CSS class list im trying to remove after it scrolls over the first page:

```
.navbar {
background: transparent !important;
z-index: 10;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

and this is the the CSS classlist im trying to add after scrolling into the second page or beyond:

```
.navbar-active{
position: fixed;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .692) !important;
box-shadow: 0 3px 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

and finally this is my JS code to replace the classlists:

```
const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');

window.onscroll = function(){
const top = window.scrollY;
if(top >= 693){
    navbar.classList.add('.navbar-active');
} else {
    navbar.classList.remove('.navbar-active');
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't put a `.` on your classString that you're passing to `classList.add()`

Comment: You must change to this  for it to work `const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];`

Comment: @MosiaThabo yes your answer worked , Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing navbar incorrectly, you must access it either by:

One: `const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];`
*Remember that getElementsByClassName returns list of elements with that class name*

OR

Two: `const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');`

Your second mistake  is here:`navbar.classList.add('.navbar-active')`, don't put a `.` on your parameter string.

Just pass it like this:

`navbar.classList.add('navbar-active')`

Comment: That is true but it's not the main problem, or the reason for the error message.

Comment: You can check again, I have solved another problem that I didn't realize earlier on. The way you accessed your `navbar` by using `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Indeed, I started writing my answer as soon as I'd made my comment, but see I was too slow...

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because `document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object - and this has no `classList` property. Which should all make perfect sense when you think about it - multiple elements can have a particular class, and it doesn't make sense to talk about the list of classes of a whole set of elements, as opposed to just one.

You clearly only want to add or remove the class from a single element - so, assuming you only have one element with class `"navbar"`, you can do either this:

```
const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];`
```

which gets the first (and presumably only) element with the navbar class, or

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
```

which always returns the first element with the given selector. Both of these alternatives return an individual element, which has the `classList` property you expect.

Another way would be to use an I'D rather than a class - which is more logical if you know you will only use it once. `document.getElementById('navbarId')` also works, because there should be only one element in the document with a given ID.

Also, as @MosiaThabo points out in his answer/comment, you have an extraneous dot at the start of the class name you're trying to add.

Comment: i got it now , Thank you so much for the explanation , it helped me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

In classlist you only write classnames, so you do not need to write the dot (.)
So your code should be:

```
navbar.classList.add('navbar-active');
```

But I strongly recommend to use ID as selector instead of class:

```
#navbar { 
background: transparent !important;
z-index: 10;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

then on JS you can easily select:

```
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
```

This is a more efficient way from the performance perspective.